# How to display data in mail in proper format from Sql server database table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I am sending mail when a user registers to a mail Id through database.I want space between the text fields in mail body.

SQL query:

```
SELECT @Message =@MessageHeader + char(13) + char(10)+CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
 +'Company Name: ' +  IsNull([CompanyName],'') + char(13) + char(10)         
 + 'Contact Name:' + IsNull([ContactName],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + 'Contact Email:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([ContactEmail],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + ' Password:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([Password],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + 'Phone Number:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([PhoneNumber],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + 'Address:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([Address],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + 'Country:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([Country],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + 'State:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([State],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + 'City:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([City],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + 'Zip:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([Zipcode],'') +char(13) +char(10) 
 + 'Fax:'+ CHAR(9) + CHAR(9)  + IsNull([Fax],'') +char(13) +char(10) 

FROM MemTable WHERE MemberID= @MemberID
```

Now output in mail is:

```
Member ID:   22736
Company Name: tesCFS
Contact Name: tesCFS
Contact Email: tesCFS@tesCFS.com
Password: tesCFS
Phone Number: 213
Address:     tesCFS
Country:    
State:  
City:   
Zip:    
Fax:
```

I want the output as:

```
Member ID:          22736
Company Name:       tesCFS
Contact Name:       tesCFS
Contact Email:      tesCFS@tesCFS.com
Password:           tesCFS
Phone Number:       213
Address:            tesCFS
Country:    
State:  
City:   
Zip:    
Fax:
```

Comment: You would be better off separating concerns by selecting the raw data in individual variables then building up whatever string you want out of this data.

Comment: Isn't your output AS-IS and TO-BE thesame?

Comment: Do this in your app/display layer, not in the database.

Comment: There are scenarios where it's reasonable to have the database server send the email rather than whatever front end or separate app might be available. For example, what if @son wants to send an email to internal users when a new external user registers? It's a lot easier to have the database server create that than to build a separate app to poll the database for recent registrations and then compose and send the email. In those cases, it's reasonable to want a well-formatted email, which seems to be what he's asking about.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you want the two columns to line up. You could consider using the HTML email format, wrapping things up in manually constructed table row elements. It's not elegant, but it's effective.

If you want to keep it text, you will need to use a variable number of tabs depending on how long your names are, and the quantity will depend on how many spaces the display program (presumably, an email client) affords each tab character. You could instead REPLICATE spaces for absolute control. See below code examples.

In either case, you will either have to (1) manually compute and code however many tabs or spaces you need or (2) have the names themselves be returned by a table and then perform calculations on them based on their length.

```
SELECT

-- Option 1, using tabs and manually figuring out how many are required
'Message Header' + char(13) + char(10)+CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
+ 'Company Name:' +  CHAR(9) + IsNull(CompanyName,'') + char(13) + char(10)         
+ 'Contact Name:' + CHAR(9) + IsNull(ContactName,'') +char(13) +char(10) 
+ 'Zip:' + CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + CHAR(9) + IsNull(Zip,'') +char(13) +char(10) AS Option1,

-- Option 2, using spaces and manually figuring out how many are required
'Message Header' + char(13) + char(10)+CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
+ 'Company Name:' + REPLICATE(' ',3) + IsNull(CompanyName,'') + char(13) + char(10)         
+ 'Contact Name:' + REPLICATE(' ',3) + IsNull(ContactName,'') +char(13) +char(10) 
+ 'Zip:' + REPLICATE(' ',12) + IsNull(Zip,'') +char(13) +char(10) AS Option2,

-- Option 3, using dynamic space calculation
'Message Header' + char(13) + char(10)+CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)
+ CompanyNamePrefix + ':' + REPLICATE(' ',(ColNum-LEN(CompanyNamePrefix))) + IsNull(CompanyName,'') + char(13) + char(10)         
+ ContactNamePrefix + ':' + REPLICATE(' ',(ColNum-LEN(ContactNamePrefix))) + IsNull(ContactName,'') +char(13) +char(10) 
+ ZipPrefix + ':' + REPLICATE(' ',(ColNum-LEN(ZipPrefix))) + IsNull(ZipPrefix,'') +char(13) +char(10) AS Option3

FROM
(
    SELECT
        15 AS ColNum,
        'Company Name' AS CompanyNamePrefix,
        'Contact Name' AS ContactNamePrefix,
        'Zip' AS ZipPrefix
) AS Names
CROSS JOIN
(
    SELECT
         'Ed''s Company' AS CompanyName,
         'Ed' AS ContactName,
         '55120' AS Zip
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        'Bill''s Company',
        'Bill',
        '90210'
) AS MemTable;
```

Comment: I have tried the option ! but it did not work let me try other 2 option.@Riley Major